# C++: Setting a uint32 to an int32 (negative value)

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-warnings, uint32, int32

I am debating whether I can get rid of a compiler warning or not. The warning comes from comparing an uint32 to -1.

Now just from glancing at it this seems like an unwise thing to do since uint32 should never be negative yet I didn't write this code and am not as familiar with the c++ way of doing things, so I am asking you. Here is some example code to illustrate what's happening.

```
  bool isMyAddressValid = false;
  unsigned int myAddress(-1);
  unsigned int translatedAddress;

  if(isMyAddressValid)
  {
      translatedAddress = 500;
  }
  else
  {
      translatedAddress = -1;
  }

  myAddress = translatedAddress;

  if(myAddress == -1)
  {
      std::cout << "ERROR OCCURED";
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "SUCCESS";
  }`
```

So is this valid code? Is this come Cism that I do not properly understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an `unsigned` type to -1 is the idiomatic way of setting it to its maximum possible value, regardless of the number of bits in the type.

A clumsier but perhaps clearer way would be to write

```
translatedAddresss = std::numeric_limits<decltype(translatedAddresss)>::max();
```

Comment: Or  using  UINT_MAX.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: But that constains the type. `-1` works for any unsigned type.

Comment: Would the code ever go into the if(myAddress==-1) block?

Comment: @TeeseCaprice: Absolutely! -1 and "the max value" for your type are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your arsenal of libraries, I would use  [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid according to the standard, both assignment and equality check applies integer conversions on its operands. It is, however, a C-ism to use a sentinel value, I would use an exception instead.